# Metamask vault location in Windows 10 Firefox

Tags: windows, metamask

The location of the Metamask vault for Chrome on Windows 10 is `$HOME_DIR/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Local Extension Settings/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn`.

I'm looking for the location of metamask settings in Windows 10 for Firefox.

I would expect to find the vault here:
`$HOMEDIR\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\` but it is not there.

No answer in that thread: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2749

What is the mysterious place the vault is hidden?

**EDIT**

Searched for AppData folder, nothing is found.

[image]